# Can't add a repo

Tags: ppa

I wanted to install elementary+ icons, but got an error while trying to add devs PPA:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybre/elementaryplus/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried various solutions I found but none of them worked. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

This PPA has no releases for Juno (Bionic). You can force it by changing "Bionic" to "Xenial" in repo list file (/etc/apt/sources.list.d/) but I wouldn't recommend it.

Try these instead [Uratu icons](https://github.com/btd1337/urutau-icons).